# Is Liferay the same as Spring?

Tags: spring, liferay

Is Liferay the same as Spring?  Are they two different types of products?  I can't tell if Liferay is a CMS, framework, or all of the above.  Do I need something like JBoss to run it Liferay?

Comment: Liferay is neither a CMS nor a framework. It's a portal (that contains - amongst others - a portlet that is a CMS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Is Liferay the same as Spring?
```

No. Liferay is a [Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_portal). Spring is a framework for application development.

Spring is mainly used to address [Inverion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

A portal can be seen as a collection of small/mini web-applications 
(providing limited features and information) normally called as portlets.

Please check SO info about [Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/portal/info) and [Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring/info) for more details.

```
Are they two different types of products?
```

Purpose for which they are used is different, but one can [integrate Liferay with Spring](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding+Spring+Capabilitites+to+Hook)
to make application development faster and efficient.

```
I can't tell if Liferay is a CMS, framework, or all of the above.
```

Liferay is a Portal which among other features supports CMS.

```
Do I need something like JBoss to run it Liferay?
```

Liferay comes as a bundled package with Servlet Container like Tomcat or
a fully fledged Java EE container like Jboss, Glass fish etc.
You can [download community edition](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases) here.